# Runtime polymorphism in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, polymorphism, overriding

Is there any elegant way to apply polymorphism in this case? The parser provides the following classes at runtime:

```
class io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema //is parent of the rest :

class io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.ComposedSchema
class io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.ArraySchema
class io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.StringSchema
class io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.ObjectSchema
```

I'd like to have function for each class with the same name and simple, short method which will cast and call necessary function at runtime. Which is actually happening, but I hope there is more brief solution, without necessity of making this kind of duplicates:

```
fun main() {

    val parser = OpenAPIV3Parser()
    val asList = listOf(pathYaml3, pathYml2)
    val map = asList.map(parser::read)
            .flatMap { it.components.schemas.values }
            .forEach(::parseRawSchema)
}


fun parseRawSchema(schema: Schema<Any>) {

    if (schema is ComposedSchema) {
        parseSchema(schema)
    }
    if (schema is StringSchema) {
        parseSchema(schema)
    }
...
}

fun parseSchema(schema: ComposedSchema) {
    println("Compose-schema")
}

fun parseSchema(schema: StringSchema) {
    println("Sting-schema")
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use [extension](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html). 
For example:

```
fun ComposedSchema.parseSchema() {
    println("Compose-schema")
}

fun StringSchema.parseSchema() {
    println("Sting-schema")
}
```

And than:

```
fun parseRawSchema(schema: Schema<Any>) {
    schema.parseSchema()
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't call this extended function on `schema` untill I create extention for `Schema<Any>.class` but when I do, the programm will use only it. I also not able to add any `override` modifiers to this extentions. But its interesting approach anyway, may be I'm one step further. Thanks!